# Wordpress menu items order

Tags: wordpress, menu

basically I have a three-level menu in wordpress and I've got the following code in the front-end to call the third-level menu:

$children = get_pages('child_of='.$include_page_ids[$i]);

```
    if (count($children) > 1) {

        $sub = "<ul>";

        foreach ($children as $child){

        $sub .= "<li><a href='#$child->post_title'>";

        $sub .= $child->post_title;

        $sub .= "</a></li>";

        }

        $sub .="</ul>";

        echo $sub;

    }
```

This calls a list for the children of a certain page and also  makes the the anchors (which I also need). The problem is that right now they are being displayed in an alphabetical order, but I need to be able to set the right order myself (ie to be the same as in the backend menu). Please hepl me with it, how can I achieve this? For example this is the page http://www.eboxlab.net/transbeam/support/support/, youcan see the third level-menu as the box right next to the banner (Acceptable Use Policy to Terms & Conditions). THe order of the blocks which it corresponds to is right, but the menu is alphabetically ordered.
Help really appreciated.
PS: if you need I can provide the template code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually. Here is what your `$children` call should look like:
`$children = get_pages('child_of=' . $include_page_ids[$i] . '&orderby=menu_order&sort_order =ASC');`

That's all you need to add - this tells the query to order pages in ascending fashion by their "menu_order" column(or the "Order" field under **Page attributes**). You can see more details on the get_pages function at [Function Reference/get pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Answer (score 0):

[wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to the rescue! Assuming you're using WP 3 or newer, it will let you wrap elements in whatever markup you'd like, and will correspond to however you've configured the menu in the admin Dashboard.

Comment: Complementing the answer, this guide can help you: http://wptutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/090_WPCheatSheets/WP_CheatSheet_ThemeAnatomy.jpg